# What would happen if my iOS distribution certificate is compromised?

Tags: ios, application-security, ios-app-signing, mobile-security

I am an iOS newbie and would really like to focus on the security of my iOS app signing certificates.

In my understanding, for a malicious actor to be able to misuse my leaked distribute certificate would need to crack through following 3 layers to distribute malicious version of my app to the innocent customers:

**Step 1**:
My iOS project source code. Let us assume this was leaked too via some weakly configured VCS such as Git

**Step 2**:
Required to install the distribution provisioning profile on the attacker's device. For a moment, let us assume this was performed too.

**Step 3**:
App Store/Test Flight privileges to upload and release the application to the App Store.

Since app signed by distribution certificates can't be installed on individual devices unless attached to a certain provisioning profile such as Ad Hoc or In House, there is nothing much an attacker would be able to achieve.

Is this correct understanding? Can someone please help me in understanding the threat model better?

Comment: Step 1 isn't really necessary. All I need is to create an app that looks convincing enough for your user to input whatever data I want, or snoop through the stored data for your app. Now, the phishing part is probably too hard to achieve since step 2 & step 3 imply either the user device/your account has been compromised, but snooping part is a good start if say I stole/temporarily hold the victim device and I want to get their login token or whatever secret your app use, so I can copy them to my own app (signed with your cert), then load your original app and impersonate them.

Comment: fwiw, any app would go through app store review. Only a person with your appropriate access can submit apps signed with your certificate to the app store. Once they do that you'll get emails that your app is in review, then available for distribution, etc. But if your login creds to your Apple developer account has also been compromised then well your screwed big time.